# Modify datatype of date column into integer datatype

Tags: oracle19c

I have a table of millions or records and now the requirement is to change the datatype of the date column into integer.

Can we do this ? If yes then how? without loosing any data.

Thanks

Comment: An *additional* virtual column with a numeric version of the date might make more sense than replacing the current column - you would keep the benefits of using the correct data type (validation, optimisation) while having both data types available.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date to a formatted string and then to a number:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(your_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) AS date_number
FROM   your_table
```

Or you could convert the values to be relative to an epoch:

```sql
SELECT ROUND((your_date - DATE '1970-01-01')*86400) AS seconds_since_1970
FROM   your_table
```

If you want to add a virtual column to the database to do the conversion then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD date_number INTEGER
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(your_date, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')));
```

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD seconds_since_1970 INTEGER
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ROUND((your_date - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400));
```

Then the table would contain:

> | YOUR_DATE | DATE_NUMBER | SECONDS_SINCE_1970 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-04-26T14:36:48 | 20220426143648 | 1650983808 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ac0202242d4096eccfa17bf2a59ae2d)*

Answer (score 1):

Modify, no.

Realistically, you'd want to add a new `integer` column to the table, move the data to the new column, drop the old column, and rename the new column.  Something like

```
alter table foo
  add( new_column integer );

update foo
   set new_column = to_number( to_char( old_column, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) );

alter table foo
  drop column old_column;

alter table foo
  rename column new_column to old_column;
```

It may be more efficient to set the old column to `unused` rather than dropping it depending on how big your table is and what sort of window you have.

And this doesn't address the underlying wisdom of the requirement.  If you have data that represents a `date`, it very seldom makes sense to store that data as an `integer` or a `varchar2` or anything other than a `date`.

Comment: What will happen to the index and partitions if these are based on that column?

Comment: @Astitva - You'd need to re-create any indexes.  If you have a table that is partitioned on the `date` column, that's very important information that should be in your question.  And that would strongly suggest that you don't want to change the data type of the column in the first place.